# How can I output a list of all users who have read (and/or write) permissions for a specific file in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, file-permissions, users

Suppose I have a file MyFile. Are there any commands that will print to console a list of all users in the system that can read the file?

Comment: [This Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10857461/2001600) might give you some guidance. It's probably not a lot of help because the solution is pretty abstract, but it might be a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible unless you write your own script. However, you can easily check file permissions by using `ls -l filename`; it will output something like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hector users 1850 Apr 1 22:50 filename
```

The first field is the Unix permission bits. The first trio is for the owner, the second for the group, and the third for everyone else. For this particular file, the owner "hector" can read and write and all users in the group "users" can as well, while everyone else can only read. The files `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` will tell you what users you have and what groups they're in, respectively. For more information use `info coreutils 'file permissions'`.

Comment: And to add to the proposed answer: Anyone in the SUDO-ers group and "root" user will have access to your files.